# Can data from yodlee be exported into other programs?

Tags: xml, database, yodlee

I am looking to export clients investment, banking and other data from yodlee to another program such as E-money.  I am inquiring if this data could be exported in a condensed format such as an Excel spreadsheet so that it could be easily imported into another program?

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee provides API's which will return data in JSON format if you use REST. You need to call those APIs get the data and create a format which you can use to import into any other program. Yodlee also provides Data Extracts for further information; I would suggest you to get in touch with Yodlee Sales Representative. Here is the [link](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html).